# Widget for float painting

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

Are there any widget or option for painting anything at non integer (e.g 3.5) position? I currently use a QWidget, a QGraphicsView and a QGraphicsScene. However, the widget only supports painting at integer pixel locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QPainter supports floating point coordinates, but has to be done using an implicit QPointF statement:

`qp.drawPoint(QPointF(10.5, 10))`

[image: parameters]

Answer (score 1):

What is it you are really trying to do? There are many float/real methods to choose from so it doesn't sound like you are asking the correct question.

[mapFromScene()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mapFromScene-5)
[centerOn()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn)

In C++ when you [addWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) you get back QGraphicsProxyWidget *. and it just so happens that QGraphicsProxyWidget has [setPos(qreal x, qreal y)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos-1)

I'm certain you can find something similar in the Python interface. If you cannot, convert your QWidget to a QGraphicsItem which also has a setPos(qreal x, qreal y)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that is not the problem I had. As you can see in the picture, `drawPoint` method supports `QPointF` (float coordinates), but I passed directly the x and y values, and using that way x and y must be ints

Comment: Sounds more like trying to make a failed design work. Best of luck.